# Сохранение данных из инпутов в массив, в дальнейшем для сохранения всего в localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, json

Есть большой json file - контактная книга. Моя задача, получить его, вывести имена в select и по нажатию на n имя получать его данные [Сам json, собственно](http://demo.sibers.com/users). Я спарсил, вывел имена в div с селектом. Нажимаю на имя, всё работает, инфу выводит в input'ы - возможность их изменять и часть задания. Теперь следующее:

**1. Нужно, что бы по нажатию на кнопку "Save", данные из инпутов перезаписывали данные данного контакта в массиве.**

**2. И всё это дело летело в localstorage и, соответственно, при обновлении
    страницы, данные выводились уже измененные.**

У меня есть массив "database" с ключом key
В функции slctt работает штука "database[key.**selectedIndex**].здесь какое-либо значение ключа - name, username, email etc."
Либо я не так всё начал делать изначально, либо не знаю, как мне **selectedIndex** использовать в другой функции - save, что бы можно было перезаписать измененные данные с инпута.
Букв много, извиняюсь заранее, но я уже хз, что делать.
Если что-то не дописал и что-то непонятно, пишите, сразу отвечу

```js
database = [];
//array_data = [];
function ajax_get(url, callback) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            try {
                var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            } catch(err) {
                console.log(err.message + " in " + xmlhttp.responseText);
                return;
            }
            callback(data);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
 


ajax_get('http://demo.sibers.com/users', function(data) {     
    for (var key in data){
        database[key] = data[key];
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(database[key]));
        $('#names').append($('<option>',
            {   
            id: 'name',
            text : (data[key].name),
            }));
    } 
});

function slctt(key){
    $('#wrapper').empty();
    array_data = [
        database[key.selectedIndex].name,   
        database[key.selectedIndex].username,
        database[key.selectedIndex].email,
        database[key.selectedIndex].address.streetA,
        database[key.selectedIndex].address.streetB,
        database[key.selectedIndex].address.streetC,
        database[key.selectedIndex].address.streetD,
        database[key.selectedIndex].address.city,
        database[key.selectedIndex].address.state,
        database[key.selectedIndex].address.country,
        database[key.selectedIndex].address.zipcode,
        database[key.selectedIndex].address.geo.lat,
        database[key.selectedIndex].address.geo.lng,
        database[key.selectedIndex].phone,
        database[key.selectedIndex].website,
        database[key.selectedIndex].company.name,
        database[key.selectedIndex].company.catchPhrase,
        database[key.selectedIndex].company.bs,
        database[key.selectedIndex].posts[0].words[0],
        database[key.selectedIndex].posts[0].words[1],
        database[key.selectedIndex].posts[0].words[2],
        database[key.selectedIndex].posts[0].sentence,
        database[key.selectedIndex].posts[0].sentences,
        database[key.selectedIndex].posts[0].paragraph,
        database[key.selectedIndex].posts[1].words[0],
        database[key.selectedIndex].posts[1].words[1],
        database[key.selectedIndex].posts[1].words[2],
        database[key.selectedIndex].posts[1].sentence,
        database[key.selectedIndex].posts[1].sentences,
        database[key.selectedIndex].posts[1].paragraph,
        database[key.selectedIndex].posts[2].words[0],
        database[key.selectedIndex].posts[2].words[1],
        database[key.selectedIndex].posts[2].words[2],
        database[key.selectedIndex].posts[2].sentence,
        database[key.selectedIndex].posts[2].sentences,
        database[key.selectedIndex].posts[2].paragraph,
        database[key.selectedIndex].accountHistory[0].amount,
        database[key.selectedIndex].accountHistory[0].date,
        database[key.selectedIndex].accountHistory[0].business,
        database[key.selectedIndex].accountHistory[0].name,
        database[key.selectedIndex].accountHistory[0].type,
        database[key.selectedIndex].accountHistory[0].account,
        database[key.selectedIndex].accountHistory[1].amount,
        database[key.selectedIndex].accountHistory[1].date,
        database[key.selectedIndex].accountHistory[1].business,
        database[key.selectedIndex].accountHistory[1].name,
        database[key.selectedIndex].accountHistory[1].type,
        database[key.selectedIndex].accountHistory[1].account,
        database[key.selectedIndex].accountHistory[2].amount,
        database[key.selectedIndex].accountHistory[2].date,
        database[key.selectedIndex].accountHistory[2].business,
        database[key.selectedIndex].accountHistory[2].name,
        database[key.selectedIndex].accountHistory[2].type,
        database[key.selectedIndex].accountHistory[2].account,
        database[key.selectedIndex].favorite,
        database[key.selectedIndex].avatar
    ];
   
    for(var i=0; i<array_data.length; i++){
    $('#wrapper').append($('<input>',{
            id: 'info',
            value : JSON.stringify(array_data[i]),
            size: '70',
            }));
    }
}



function save(key){
    var s = name;
    var sv = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i=0; i < sv.length; i++){
        array_data[i] = sv[i].value;
        database[key] = array_data[i];
        //console.log(array_data[i]);
        console.log(database[key]);
    }
    
}
```

```css
body{
    background: url(fond.png);
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 1%;
}
#fullinfo{
    background: grey;
    max-width: 200px;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
#names{
    width: 200px;
}
#wrapper{   
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 800px;
    float: right;
    height: 880px;
    padding-left: 3%; 
}
#info{
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 13pt;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <title>Contacts</title>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="fullinfo">
        <select id="names" size="52" onchange="slctt(this)"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="content">

        <div id="wrapper">
            
        </div>
        <button id="saveinfo" onclick="save(this)">Save</button>

    </div>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Поправьте название, чтобы оно точно отражало суть Вашего вопроса (и уберите все лишнее из него). Код вставьте кодом, а не ссылкой на архив. Если можно оформить как полностью рабочий пример, то вставляйте сниппетом (Ctrl+M).

Comment: Код не запускается из-за ошибки "Access to XMLHttpRequest..."